# C++ terminal output with constant area / status bar

Tags: terminal, ncurses

I have a larger C++ application that is entirely console/terminal controlled. A lot of debug output is printed, however it starts to get messy. Important information gets lost between general status information of the various modules. Disabling these outputs is not possible as they are actually an important indicator for malfunctions.

Instead, I thought it may be more helpful to "split" the screen, i.e. have specific output in a kind of extra area on screen (terminal). This could be thought of as a status bar (possibly multiple lines).

I could do this easily with ANSI codes, however there are still many printfs that always mess up the output. Also scrolling is broken this way.

An option would possibly be to use ncurses, however I do not want to port the whole application to it. I tried to find out whether I can have normal printf outputs shown in an ncurses application (kinda like a terminal in a terminal console :-)), but did not find any.

I am looking for any suggestion that would allow me to add something like this easily:

- have a fixed-size area (top N lines) on terminal output some status information
- the remainder of the screen shows printf output
- when scrolling, the fixed-size area / statusbar should not have an adverse effect (i.e. I want to properly scroll the printf output without losing any!)

The code will run on Linux machines on a laptop (usually using gnome terminal) or remotely via an ssh connection.

Answer (score 0):

Using ncurses to do this is not practical without converting the application to use ncurses.  ncurses expects to be the only thing manipulating the screen.

Off the top of my head I have 2 ideas for you (aside from converting your app to ncurses):

- You could use some crazy linker or #define tricks to replace all calls to printf, etc. with versions that use ncurses to write to the screen.  I don't recommend this.
- You could pipe the output into an app that takes input on stdin and then uses ncurses to display the input based on some sort of regex.  (e.g. lines that start with "error" go to the top half of the screen everything else to the bottom).

If you wish to use the terminal's scroll buffer you will need to have the scrolling section at the top of the window. ncurses may not work well for this requirement since it was designed in an era when terminals did not have scrollback buffers.